# How is a sequence of sets tending to null but its measure not to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Ive been studying measure theory lately but theres a thing i cant really understand. Happens that for some exercises, its said that a measure $\mu$ has this property:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (E_n) = \emptyset \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(E_n) = 0$$

I can notice this property is necesary in some demonstrations, or for solving those exercises; but i can not imagine a good example of $\mu$ where this doesnt work.

I was thinking about $\mu$ counting the elements of a set ($\infty$ if non-countable), and an En decreasing but always non-countable. I think it works, but are there less trivial examples?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure, let $E_n = (n, \infty)$. Then each $\mu(E_n) = \infty$ but $\lim E_n = \emptyset$.

Comment: Note that if you work in a finite measure space you always get continuity of measure from above, ie if $\bigcap_n E_n$ is null then $\lim_n\mu(E_1\cap\cdots\cap E_n)=0$

Answer (score 1):

There's already a great example in the comments, but another example would be $E_n = \cup_{i>0}(i, i+\frac{1}{n})$

Clearly: $\forall n, \mu(E_n) = \infty$

Yet we have: $\lim E_n = \cap E_n = \emptyset$

Comment: Are you using the counting measure? Or why is the measure infinite?

Comment: sorry, reused the same variable. should be fixed.